# SQL Where logic parameterized where

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlparameter

I'm attempting to create a parameterized where statement using `COALESCE` in SQL 2008, and I have the example of:

```
Select * 
From Receipts 
Where Receipts.FunctionCode = COALESCE(@FunCode, Receipts.FunctionCode)
```

in hope that if i pass in NULL in @FunCode, it will pull all 7050 records. However its only pulling back 236 records, and same as if the where was this:
Where Receipts.FunctionCode = Receipts.FunctionCode

Can someone explain what logic is wrong for me? To me, this where statement should always pull 100% back the database

Comment: Well, are there values where `Receipts.FunctionCode` are `NULL`?

Comment: `Null = Null` isn't true in SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is due to the `NULL` values present in the `FunctionCode` column try this instead. This will use index created on `FunctionCode` if any

```
Select * 
From Receipts 
Where Receipts.FunctionCode = @FunCode or @FunCode IS NULL
```